# Environment variables not getting created by Chef

Tags: linux, chef-infra, chef-recipe, rhel7

I am trying to create some new env variables in the rhel machine using chef.

The block executes successfully but on trying to echo the value, i am getting black result.

Script-1:

```
execute 'JAVA_HOME' do
      command 'export JAVA_HOME='+node['java']['home']
    end
```

Script-2:

```
bash 'env_test' do
      code <<-EOF
      echo $chef
    EOF
      environment ({ 'chef' => 'chef' })
    end
```

Also gave this a shot as it was mentioned in the documentation:

```
ENV['LIBRARY_PATH'] = node['my']['lib']
```

Please let me know where am i going wrong here..

Comment: I mean blank** result not black result..sorry for the typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the thing you need to know about environment variables is they only work in one direction (parent process to children) so an `export` in a subcommand does nothing after that `execute` resource finishes. The second and third examples both work though, with the second setting it for just that `bash` resource and the third for both the Chef process and everything it spawns. Remember that you need to run with with `-l debug` to see the output from subcommands Chef runs.

Comment: Is there a way to set up the env variables permanently using chef? is editing the /etc/environment file a good approach?

Comment: Linux has no concept of global or permanent environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Above explanation is pretty helpful. Updating the /etc/environments file using chef to make sure that env variables are present from the next session. Also using the 3rd approach to make the env variables available for the current session.